# Einstein Bot - Redirect to Dialog using variable

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I'm trying to redirect to a Dialog using a variable set by an answer to a Dynamic Question.
The options from the Dynamic Question are records from ConversationDefinitionDialog, and I'm using the MasterLabel field as the format formula.

Thought that it would work if I used that same record for redirecting, but I'm clearly missing something.

For more context, this is the doc that says it can be done, but it doesn't explain how exactly.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_einstein_bots_redirect_variable.htm&release=242&type=5

Is it expecting a ConversationDefinitionDialog record or a different kind of object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.